# references a foreign key that is a primary key with another key on the parent table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

i have those tables :

```
create table t_table(t1 int, constraint tprim primary key(t1));

create table parent_table(t1 int, p1 int, p2 int, constraint pprim primary key(t1, p1));

create table child_table(t1 int, c1 int, p1 int, constraint cprim primary key(t1, c1), constraint fchild foreign key (p1) references parent_table(p1));
```

i get this error when creating the second table :

> ```
> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
> ```

`p1` in parent_table is not unique so i can't make it unique to resolve the problem.

in this case how to say that `p1` is a foreign key in child_table that references parent_table(p1) ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. A Foreign Key references a Primary Key. Perhaps what you want to do is to include t1 in the foreign key to child_table? Or else, if you really need something like p1 to be FK in child_table, perhaps you need one more table, just for p1, with unique values? Then p1 in both parent_table and child_table is FK pointing to this additional table.

Comment: please, what did you mean by `Perhaps what you want to do is to include t1 in the foreign key to child_table?` ,  do you mean in the same foreign key constraint (with p1) if it is the case how it is possible if the two keys belong to different tables?

Comment: @youzking - they don't belong to different tables. (t1, p1) in child_table references (t1, p1) in parent_table - even if neither t1 alone nor p1 alone is PK to parent_table. The pair IS primary key, and that you are allowed to reference from child_table.

Comment: oh yes of course, because t1 was first a primary key in t_table i imagine that it belongs to t_table , i forget it was just the same name in child_table.
thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible you must reference a primary key